# How to save current index of ComboBox for supported map types

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I try to save index of ComboBox for choosing supported map types of Open Street Map. When opening the app again, the last chosen map index should be displayed. `Qt.labs.settings` didn't work as the example below:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow{
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true
    Settings{
            id:mycombo
            property alias maptype: selectmap.currentIndex
        }
    Flickable {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        clip: true
        contentHeight: Math.max(mapColumn.implicitHeight, height)
        Column{
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            id:mapColumn
            spacing: 5
            anchors.fill : parent
            Row{
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                spacing:25
                Rectangle{
                    width:mapColumn.width
                    height:mapColumn.height-80
                    Map {
                          id:map
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            plugin: Plugin {
                              name: "osm"
                          }
                      }
               }
          }

          Column{
              id: combos
              spacing: 10
              width: parent.width
              anchors.verticalCenter: root.verticalCenter
                  Row{
                      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                      spacing:1
                      Label{ text:"Map Type: "; height: selectmap.height; verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter; }
                      // Map Types
                      ComboBox {
                          id: selectmap
                          width: 200
                          model:map.supportedMapTypes
                          textRole:"description"
                          onCurrentIndexChanged: map.activeMapType = map.supportedMapTypes[currentIndex]

                      }
                  }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to save the current index of ComboBox for maps?

Comment: The problem is map.supportedMapTypes.
That vector isn't populated until map emits mapReady.
Meaning that, when you restart the app, if you have a binding on that vector, it will start by being empty, and selectmap index will be clamped to 0

Comment: It works when I set the current index in Timer after (1 second). Setting the current doesn't work in onMapReadyChanged. I don't know why it works in Timer{} but it doesn't work when map is ready.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "opening the app again" it is possible that the app has been killed, and in that case all values are lost. You have to store the index value in the file system, like config data, which is read when application loads. I guess there will be several of these data, including last typed places and history(for which cache is better). However for config data you may use JSON format.

Make a JSON file where you store all data, and make a controller like GuiConfigurationController which parses the file with QJsonValue. You may also consider to make a GuiConfiguration Singletonn class which will have all the values loaded as getter method. To write to the JSON file from QML use the Q_PROPERTY WRITE method which calls the setter method for the variable.

```
Q_PROPERTY(quint32 savedIndex READ savedIndex WRITE setSavedIndex NOTIFY savedIndexChanged)

quint32 savedIndex() const {return m_savedIndex;}
void setSavedIndex(quint32 index) {m_savedIndex = index;}
```

QML:

```
_someController.savedIndex = currentIndex
```

make sure _someController is set as rootContext -> ContextProperty to QQuickView

so when index changes the value is set in someController which saved the value to JSON. When app is loading read JSON and get the value of index. Update QtQuick using the onLoaded method

```
onLoaded: {currentindex = _someController.savedIndex}
```

Comment: The app stores the index value in app.conf file in the file system using Qt.labs.settings module (for Ubuntu it is in /home/$user/.config/app/ folder). Current index can be stored and can be reloaded when reopening the app. if ComboBox has a static model it works. But it doesn't work for dynamically created model.

Comment: The index only makes sense if the order of loaded elements remains same every time. By saying dynamically created model if you mean the order of elements may vary, then store the element instead of the index, then via C++ search the current index of the element and set the value in QML.

Comment: Order of elements don't vary. I tried to set `currentIndex: 3` in ComboBox, it didn't work. There are 6 items but it doesn't set the current index. I get this error: `Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QDeclarativeGeoMapType*` But the ComboBox currentIndex works when setting model as model: ["a", "b", "c"]